# Is disconnectedness local? 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $F$ is a closed set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$ and $V$ an open set that contains $F$. It seems correct that if $V$ is connected and $V\setminus F$ is disconnected, then $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ is also disconnected. Is it true?

I can prove it if $V$ is closed, but not if it is open. In fact, we have $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F=(V\setminus F)\cup (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus V)$. If $V\setminus F=A_1\cup A_2$ with $\overline{A_1}\cap A_2=\overline{A_2}\cap A_1=\emptyset$, since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are in $V$ and $V$ is closed, their closures are also in $V$. From there is is easy to show that the closure of $A_1$ has an empty intersection with $A_2 \cup(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus V)$, and same with $A_1$ and the closure of $A_2 \cup(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus V)$. But it seems the same proof won't work if $V$ is open.

Comment: The answer is YES. You will have to show some effort before you can expect an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Consider the covering of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by open subsets $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ and $V$.
We have the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for reduced homology:
$$
\widetilde{H}_1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{Z})\to \widetilde{H}_0(V\setminus F,\mathbb{Z})\to \widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F,\mathbb{Z})\oplus \widetilde{H}_0(V,\mathbb{Z})\to \widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{Z}).
$$
We have $\widetilde{H}_i(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $i$.
Moreover, since $V$ is connected, we have $\widetilde{H}_0(V,\mathbb{Z})=0$.
Therefore we have
$$
\widetilde{H}_0(V\setminus F,\mathbb{Z})\cong\widetilde{H}_0(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F,\mathbb{Z}).
$$
If $V\setminus F$ is not connected, the left hand side is non-zero.
Then the right hand side is also non-zero, so $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F$ is not connected.

Comment: Thanks. But there is not another way to prouve it without using algebraic topology?

Comment: I think it is difficult.  The statement fails to hold if we use non-simply-connected manifolds (e.g. $(S^1)^n$) instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so we have to use some special properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. vanishing of the 1st homology group).

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a book where to find the prerequisite to understand your proof? Do you think James Munkres is sufficient?

Comment: Probably any book that deals with singular homology will do.  I have not read Munkres' book, but I recommend Chapter 2 of Hatcher's book.

Comment: @ Jun Koizumi: I try to see in the literature the Mayer-Vietors sequence you used here, but I dont find this version. What I see is that $H_n(A\cap B)\to H_n(A)+H_n(B)\to H_n(X)\to...$. Where did you get this version? I didn't find he version you used  in Hatcher's book.